# Accidental downvote, realised after two hours

Tags: support, feature-request, downvotes

I accidentally downvoted a really good snippet of code that actually helped me. Unfortunately, when I realised I got an error trying to rectify the mistake.

The answer in question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12073686/2982796

Two questions firstly - What should I do? I don't feel like I am in the position to edit the question as I am not a Python developer - Needed this code to quickly paste into another sample I found online.

Secondly, as it was my first downvote, should there be a confirm downvote dialog box? Only shown on the first go to explain what will happen and ask to confirm.

Comment: I edited the post; the grammar is terrible on that (as is the answer, really). Your vote is unlocked.

Comment: Thank you. Feel much less terrible.

Comment: Really, downvoting is part of the site and explained in the [site tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). I see no need to 'confirm' anything.

Comment: It is - does the site tour launch when you register, sorry it was such a long time ago - No need to confirm always, just perhaps the first ever time.

Comment: You are also notified when you reach 125 points that you can now have earned the privilege to downvote, and the [privilege page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) explains what that means. Confirming again makes little sense.

Comment: Fair enough, well now I feel ultra silly as I clicked the up-vote assuming that it would take away the down-vote, to level back out at no votes. Clearly I need to re-read up on how this site works...

Comment: Click on the highlighted vote button again to undo. Click on the other vote button to change your vote to the other direction.

Comment: I accidentally upvoted something today that I meant to downvote. Not sure if I should edit it and change it to a downvote lol.

Comment: Someone has a weird idea about what a terrible answer is. William, I upvoted that answer, as well as this question, thanks.

Comment: @WilliamGeorge: if it helped you, why "level back out at no votes"?

Comment: @BradWerth - Good point, knowing absolutely zero python - I feared up voting a potentially inefficient answer as these days people don't go on correct answers - They see the most up voted answer as presumably a much better solution. In this case, its clearly not going to overtake the accepted answer, and it very much solved my issue - Converting a ByteArray into a String - (I have noticed the title of the question has changed causing that answer to now feel out of place).

Comment: Upvote things that are helpful, downvote things that are not well researched or are unclear.  Dont over think it.  The tooltip on the arrows is a great reminder.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I would be okay with displaying a confirmation message the first time, like you suggested, except that you can easily undo an accidental vote. The downvote arrow glows orange, and a simple click on it reverses the damage.

Moreover, you only earn the privilege to *down* vote after you've had the privilege to *up* vote for some period of time. The idea is, therefore, that you already understand how the voting system works, which would make a confirmation unnecessary and annoying.

What happened to you doesn't seem like confusion in understanding how the voting system works, it sounds like a fat-fingered mistake. Which is no big deal, we all make them sometimes. The normal case would have been that you noticed it relatively quickly after casting the erroneous vote, in which case the system would have let you easily reverse it.

However, since you didn't notice it until several hours later, you discovered that the system has locked your vote in. It is necessary to do this to prevent gaming the system through voting. I know that you're an above-the-board person who would never do this, but there are some users that will downvote every competing answer upon answering a question, hoping to drive their own answer to the top of the sort order and thus accumulate even more upvotes from future visitors. Since downvotes on answers cost reputation, they'll come back later once their own answer is decidedly in the lead and remove their votes. Locking in the votes after a certain period of time allows us to prevent this type of fraud, while still allowing honest mistakes to be undone.

There is, however, a workaround, which Martijn has already pointed out: you can *edit* the post that you've voted on, which will unlock your vote so that it can be undone or converted to a different type. The idea here is that when a post is edited, its content changes, and therefore your opinion of it might change. But it also works as an escape hatch to undo a vote that has been locked in. Doing this regularly would naturally still be considered an abuse of the system. But it serves as a workaround for the rare cases, like this one. Plus, we do ask something of you in return for the privilege to change your vote—we ask that you take the time to improve another's contribution to the site. If you're doing that each time you post a competing answer, well…more power to you.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to explain further. I was unaware such down-voting took place. Indeed you are correct, it must have been the fat fingers (y)

Comment: There is the point that the latest software "hides" your vote if you jump away and back.

Comment: @HotLicks: That only happens to me when I have JS disabled...

Comment: That's really the reason why there is a locking mechanism? It seems that mankind is just there for cheating, fighting and doing other kind of bad things. *facepalm*

Comment: "Locking in the votes after a certain period of time allows us to prevent this type of fraud" I don't think that prevents fraud. If gaming the system doesn't work, people would stop it. If gaming the system does work, one would get at least one upvote, which means enough reputation to downvote 10 other answers, that's enough for most questions. So either there is no fraud or fraud isn't prevented.

Comment: Well okay. Perhaps "prevents" was the wrong word. I should have used "deters". People who obsess over reputation like this won't want to permanently give up the reputation required to downvote all competing answers. If you want to do it, you can, but it'll cost you. If there were no cost, I suspect more people would do it.

Comment: "but there are some users that will downvote every competing answer upon answering a question, hoping to drive their own answer to the top of the sort order and thus accumulate even more upvotes from future visitors." !!! I'm outraged! (A bit naive also). I mean, we all want to have rep, especially in the beginning. But What are such kind of people doing here??

Comment: Well you could easily do this without locking, i.e. you need not give back the rep to the voter after the grace period, but I should be still able to revert the vote, so A) the answerer is not cost rep, and B) others see the count and benefit from the answer.

Comment: @Manquer: That could be worth a discussion, but make sure you don't lose more than one point by downvoting and undoing multiple times on the same post.

Comment: "Locking in the votes after a certain period of time allows us to prevent this type of fraud, while still allowing honest mistakes to be undone." False and False!

Comment: I've just made the same mistake - I clicked the down vote button by accident on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6745589/1490986) answer and didn't even realise I'd done it until a few hours later on. Unfortunately I don't have edit privileges and it's a short answer that I can't contribute anything useful to anyway. Surely there must be a better way to deal with this...?

Comment: As per @Manquer's comment - I would be happy to lose my 1 point of reputation permanently as it was my mistake. I just feel a bit bad that I've reduced someone else's without meaning to!

Comment: @CodyGray - this does answer *why* the lock is there, but it is a detail that still bothers me about stackexchange sites. (Even on SO where I have enough rep, I hesitate to edit a post just so I can undo a downvote.) Manquer's suggestion seems worthwhile. Or maybe the "gaming" should be directly addressed: don't allow (answer + downvote 2 other answers), unless you have 5K rep.