# What is the current advice for reversing an accidental downvote after it has been locked in?

Tags: support, downvotes

I realize this has been [asked and answered here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270383/584676), but the advice is from 2014 and I'm unsure if anything has changed regarding the advice or process for this scenario since then.

On mobile either last night or this morning, I accidentally downvoted a question while scrolling. However, I didn't notice until a few minutes ago when I noticed the -1 rep change. I don't care about the rep point, but it's a good answer. But it's been more than two hours so the vote is locked in now.

Is the accepted advice in this scenario still to make a minor edit to the post so I can reverse the downvote? If not, what is the correct avenue to take here?

Comment: I mean, ideally you'd make a complete and useful edit rather than a minor one, but I don't see any harm in a minor edit to remove in accidental vote if a more substantial one isn't possible.

Comment: Regardless of the advice from 2014, there's no alternative other than editing the post, however minor it is. So, yes, we're still stuck in 2014.

Comment: I have two pieces of advice. 1. Don't create bigger problems by trying to solve small problems. Don't edit as a workaround, edit to improve the post and let the ability to retract your downvote be a happy side effect of it. 2. Maybe stop building barriers which makes this take an hour and just go fix stuff in the 5 seconds it would otherwise take :)

Comment: @Gimby To address `2`, if there are improvements to the post to make, sure. In this case the answer needed no improvements. I'm not sure what you mean by `1` or `3` as it relates to this question.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest well then we have a complete failure of communication because I don't know what you mean by *"I'm not sure what you mean by 1 or 3 as it relates to this question"* :) Of course you found the one answer that is spit polished already, given your high moral standing (this meta post proves you have one), that might just imply you have to suck it up. But on the other hand I don't think anyone would bat an eye if you would do an insignificant edit to right your wrong. The site gives you the power to use as you see fit, so as long as the end result is an improvement in some way...